# Getting extent in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, extents

I am using openlayers3 and i am initializing my map like so:

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([5.8713, 45.6452]),
    zoom: 12,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })  
    }),
    view: view
});
```

Now how do i get the **[extent](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#getExtent)** array , i tried the following code:

```
var extent = map.getView().getExtent();
console.log(extent);
```

But that does't seem to be the right code, i get an erros saying

> Uncaught TypeError: map.getView(...).getExtent is not a function

can anybody explain , how do i go about getting the correct extent ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just do the following

```
map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
// Nowadays, map.getSize() is optional most of the time (except if you don't share view between different maps), so above is equivalent to the following
map.getView().calculateExtent()
```

considering that `map` is the variable referencing an instance of `ol.Map` like at [this official example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/simple.html).

To correct you, it seems you didn't understood well the API documentation.

When you do a `map.getView`, it returns an [`ol.View`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.View.html) instance and no `getExtent` method is available, hence your `Uncaught TypeError: map.getView(...).getExtent is not a function` error.

Comment: `calculateExtent()` is not even documented anywhere , i see a link , but i see no content explaining what exactly this function returns , see the link here http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#calculateExtent , i have no idea what really what function returns .

Comment: You are using the v 3.0.0 documentation now outdated (for info, the last stable version is 3.10.1) so look at the latest doc about [`calculateExtent`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.View.html#calculateExtent).

Comment: what exactly does calculateExtent return ?

Comment: calculateExtent returns an array having bottom left longitude, latitude and top right longitude and latitude. somthing like [-40,-20,29,32]. You can save this array as var ex = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()); and call each values as ex[0], ex[1], etc..