# How to add a bounding box to OpenLayers 3 map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have built a simple map using OpenLayers 3, have a look at the code below:

JavaScript code:

```
var map;

function init(){
    map = new ol.Map({
        target:'map',
        renderer:'canvas',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            center:[-8015003.33712,4160979.44405],
            zoom:5
        })
    });

    var newLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    map.addLayer(newLayer);

    /* 
        get and display extent 
        http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168590/how-to-get-extent-in-openlayers-3
    */

    var size = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

    console.log(size);

    console.log(map.getSize());


    /* ========================== */

}

/* function to remove layer */

function removeTopLayer(){
    var layers = map.getLayers();
    layers.pop();
}

/* ========================= */


/* swap layers function */

function swapTopLayer(){
    var layers = map.getLayers();
    var topLayer = layers.removeAt(2);
    layers.insertAt(1, topLayer);
}

/* =================== */
```

HTML code:

```
<body onload="init()">
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div id='map'></div>
        <button style='position:absolute; left: 10px; top:30%' onclick='removeTopLayer()'>Remove Top Layer</button>
        <button style='position:absolute; left: 10px; top:40%' onclick='swapTopLayer()'>Swap Top Layers</button>

    </body>
```

Functioning link can be found **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/ol3-tut/)**.

Now I wanted to add a bounding box, so that when the map loads, it only loads for a specific area, I searched for examples online, but  they are either of OL2 or are about a user selecting a bound box dynamically, which is not my requirement. My requirement is pretty simple, all I want is the tiles for a specific bounding box to load instead of the map for the entire world to load.

I found the below method in OpenLayers 3.0 doc's **[boundingExtent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.extent.html#.boundingExtent)**, but I am not sure how to use it. :(  So now suppose I want to add a bounding box for THIS area, how would I go about doing it, using the boundingExtent method? Can anybody explain?

I have been scratching my head over this one for quite sometime now, can anybody help me achieve my goal of have only a specific bounding box load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get your point but I really can not understand what do you expect to visually get out of it.

1. Would it be somehtig like this example? -->[clipping](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/examples/layer-clipping.html). Show the a map but hide the areas you need to be not visisble.
2. Or would it be something like this example.-->[extent+minZoom+maxZoom](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/o6wre0d3/) prevent the user moving the map in areas you need to be hidden and thus not loading these tiles. (passign `extent` during the `view` configuration prevents the map center to be outside the extent passed.)
3. Or would it be something else??????

finally, for the question concerning [boundingExtent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.extent.html#.boundingExtent). It is just creating a bbox out of the supplied points. That means get the min_x,min_y, max_x, max_y out of the supplied points (x,y's). Cannt see how this is going to help you in this case.

Comment: thanks for the detailed guidelines , basically what i want to do is , set an extent (i have added the link of the coordinates in my question) , I.E. only the tiles of that extent should load. of the examples you provided , i don't need the 1st one , regarding the secound example i think the parameter `extent:[-16655.5402445057125, 6609968.258934638,0,6809968],` might be what i was looking for. is it setting an extent for the map tiles ?

Comment: If you just dont want to draw tiles outside an extent then pass the extent during tile layer initiliasation. check the docs here -->http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html. If you want to prevent the map mooving outside this extent then pass it to the ol.view as well as the tile layer

Comment: Basically its all about the load time .. I.E. reducing the load time , i have seen the effects of passing the parameter `extent` to layers , thats probably what i need , not your initial example , i hope my understanding is correct. Thank you.

Comment: no probs. glad to help.